# [AHK ]Copying multiple Lines and pasting them modified in a single line

Tags: autohotkey

So I basically just wanna make a script that copies multiple lines of a text for example:

```
:suemote: situps ─ 60  
:sqemote: squats ─ 40
:puemote: pushups ─ 30
```

and modifies it to a single line text:

`I did today 60 situps 40 squats 30 pushups , wbu?`

Important is that it doesn't paste any text which is between the colons and that the amount of lines doesn't matter or is not given. I can already copy-paste modified text on a single line, but doing that on multiple lines seems too complicated for me. Is it possible to replace the `enter` with a `space`? It would be really nice if anyone can also explain the commands that they are using, I did that text modification thing with vStr so it would be really cool if it's possible to use it also on multiple lines.

Answer (score 0):

From the given info I could come up with this,

```
myvar =
(
:suemote: situps ─ 60  
:sqemote: squats ─ 40
:puemote: pushups ─ 30
)

clearvar := RegExReplace(myvar, ":.*?: ", "")

fixedlines := StrSplit(clearvar, "`n")

For index, actions In fixedlines
{
act .= RegExReplace(actions, "(.*?)(?: ─)(.*?)$", "$2 $1")
}

MsgBox, I did today %act%, wbu?
```

It returns as requested.

I'm no pro, if there is a more efficent way please post so I do learn as well.

Comment: Sorry for my late response, this is my current script:

```ahk
AppsKey & t (myshortcut)::
list =
While pos := RegExMatch(Clipboard, "(\w*) ─ (\d*)", m, pos ? pos + StrLen(m) : 1)
 list .= m2 " " m1 " "
Clipboard := "", Clipboard := "I did today " list " , wbu?"
ClipWait, 0
If ErrorLevel
 MsgBox, 48, Error, An error occurred while waiting for the clipboard.
return
```